# How do I add new item with key to collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel collection $Data. When I   code outputs

```
dd($Data); // it outputs the following 

Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1344 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#1342 ▶}
    1 => {#1334 ▶}
    2 => {#1346 ▶}
  ]
}
    $Data->push(['Total'=>600]);
    dd($Data);
```

When I push a Total, it does inserts but output is not as expected.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1344 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#1342 ▶}
    1 => {#1334 ▶}
    2 => {#1346 ▶}
    3 => array:1 [▼
      "Total" => 600
    ]
  ]
}
```

How do I get 3 => {#1353▶) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pushing an `Array` to `$Data`, while the other items in that `Collection` are `Object`s (`stdClass` or similar). To make this consistent, use `casting`:

```php
$Data->push((object)['Total' => 600]);
```

Now you should see `3 => {#...}` instead of `3 => array:1`.